# Calculating population density: a beginners guide

Tags: java

Okay, so I'm still pretty new to this and I don't know what is going on with my code. It looks right, but when I try to run it, it is giving me a division by zero error?

Code 1 on one page my teacher gave me:

```
 public class Country
{
   // fields
    private String name;
    private int population; 
    private int area; // in square miles

    // constructors

    // methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPopulation()
    {
        return population;
    }   

    public int getArea()
    {
        return area;
    }   

    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int newPopulation)
    {
        population = newPopulation;
    }

    public void setArea(int newArea)
    {
        area = newArea;
    }

    // population per square mile
    public int populationDensity()
    {
        int density;
        density = population / area; // integer division truncates
        return density;
    }
}
```

and another one that I've done:

```
public class A03  
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Country country1 = new Country();

      String newName = "Macau";
      int newPopulation = 453000;
      int newArea = 6;
      int density = newPopulation / newArea;

      country1.setName(newName);
      country1.setPopulation(newPopulation);
      country1.setArea(newArea);

      System.out.printf("Name: " + country1.getName());
      System.out.printf("%nPopulation: %,d ", country1.getPopulation());
      System.out.printf("%nArea: "+ country1.getArea());      
      System.out.printf("%nPopulation Density: %,d", country1.populationDensity(), "%n");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();

      Country country2 = new Country();
      String name1 = "Libya";
      int population1 = 5900000;
      int area1 = 679358;
      int density1 = population1 / area1;

      System.out.printf("Name: %s%n", name1);
      System.out.printf("Population: %,d%n", population1);
      System.out.printf("Area: %,d%n", area1);
      System.out.printf("Population Density: %,d%", country2.populationDensity(),   "%n");

      System.out.println();

      Country country3 = new Country();
      String name2 = "USA";
      int population2 = 298500000;
      int area2 = 3539225;
      int density2 = population2 / area2;

      System.out.printf("Name: %s%n", name2);
      System.out.printf("Population: %,d%n", population2);
      System.out.printf("Area: %,d%n", area2);
      System.out.println();

   }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong? Or What I'm doing that's wrong. I basically copied, pasted, and changed my variables to fit the next country's population density.

Comment: your country2 does not have an area...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main`, you didn't call any of your setter methods on `country2` or `country3`.  You only declared variables.  When an instance variable is not assigned a value, Java assigns the default value, which for primitive numeric types, is `0`.  That explains why you have a divide by zero error.

Call your setters (and getters) for `country2` and `country3`.

Comment: OMG... I can't believe I forgot that! :)
Thanks for catching that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the population and area properties of the country2 object and when call

```
      System.out.printf("Population Density: %,d%", country2.populationDensity(),   "%n");
```

you divide by zero because: in populationDensity() you divide by area and it's not set, so it's 0.